# generate JSON out of command line arguments

Tags: json, bash, jq

I want to create JSON output *with jq* that looks like this:

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "song": "Yesterday",
      "artist": "The Beatles"
    }
  ]
}
```

I assumed I have to twiddle with the "filter" of jq whose concept I don't fully get after reading the doc.

This is what I got so far:

```
$ jq --arg id 1234 \
     --arg song Yesterday \
     --arg artist "The Beatles" \
  '.' \
  <<<'{ "records" : [{ "id":"$id", "song":"$song", "artist":"$artist" }] }'
```

which prints

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id" : "$id",
      "song" : "$song",
      "artist" : "$artist"
    }
  ]
}
```

Do I modify the filter? Do I change the input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
jq --null-input               \
   --arg id 1234              \
   --arg song Yesterday       \
   --arg artist "The Beatles" \
'.records[0] = {$id, $song, $artist}'
```

Each variable reference between curly brackets is converted to a key-value pair where its name is the key, and its value is the value. And assigning the resulting object to `.records[0]` forces the creation of the surrounding structure.

Answer (score 8):

An alternate way to your original attempt, on `jq-1.6` you can use the `$ARGS.positional` attribute to construct your JSON from scratch

```
jq -n '
  $ARGS.positional | { 
    records: [ 
      { 
        id:     .[0], 
        song:   .[1], 
        artist: .[2]   
      }
    ] 
  }' --args 1234 Yesterday "The Beatles"
```

---

As for *why* your original attempt didn't work, looks you are not modifying your json at all, with your filter `'.'` you are basically just reading in and printing out "untouched". The arguments set using `--arg` need to be set to the object inside the filter.

Answer (score 2):

```
jq  --null-input\
    --argjson id     1234\
    --arg     song   Yesterday\
    --arg     artist "The Beatles"\
    '{ "records" : [{ $id, $song, $artist }] }'
```

gives

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": 1234,
      "song": "Yesterday",
      "artist": "The Beatles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with an empty JSON and add the missing bits:

```
$ jq --arg id 1234 \
     --arg song Yesterday \
     --arg artist "The Beatles" \
     '. | .records[0].id=$id | .records[0].song=$song | .records[0].artist=$artist' \
  <<<'{}'
```

Outputs

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "song": "Yesterday",
      "artist": "The Beatles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Another, cleaner, approach based on the answer of @Inian could be

```
jq -n \
   --arg id 1234
   --arg song Yesterday
   --arg artist "The Beatles"
   '{records: [{id:$id, song:$song, artist:$artist}]}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you got the JSON/JQ the wrong way round:

This should be your JQ script:

*rec.jq*

```
{
  records: [
    {
      id: $id,
      song: $song,
      artist: $artist
    }
  ]
}
```

And this should be your JSON (empty):

*rec.json*

```json
{}
```

Then:

```sh
jq --arg id 123 --arg song "Yesterday" --arg artist "The Beatles" -f rec.jq rec.json
```

Which produces:

```json
{
  "records": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "song": "Yesterday",
      "artist": "The Beatles"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) can build arrays and nested objects:

```bash
$ jo -p records[]="$(jo id=12345 song=Yesterday artist='The Beatles')"
{
   "records": [
      {
         "id": 12345,
         "song": "Yesterday",
         "artist": "The Beatles"
      }
   ]
}
```