# Either curl (and/) or Discord is not handling escapes properly (using BASH)

Tags: json, bash, curl, sed, escaping

I'm trying to automate listing players in a game server to Discord using webhooks and curl.

Some variables are:

`$PREPLAY` defined as  `PREPLAY=__Currently Connected:__` this adds the text underlined

`$MESSAGE` defined as `MESSAGE="Current Online Count: \"$NOWCOUNT\"` (this works, but had to edit for stackoverflow markup)

`$NOWCOUNT` defined by other script (This also works)

`$PLAYERS` (the list of players) - I'll get more into this in a second

The line I'm using is:

`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"embeds\": [{ \"color\": \"45044\", \"description\": \"$PREPLAY$PLAYERS\", \"title\": \"$MESSAGE\" }]}" $URL`

when I use:

`PLAYERS=$(cat /tmp/players.list | sed '/Players connected/q' | egrep -v '^$' | egrep -v "^LOG" | sed -e 's/^-/\\\\\\n/')`

The output in Discord comes out as

[image: Notice the extra ""]

Notice the extra "\"

Or if, I remove **ONE** "\" from the variable assignment above to be:

`PLAYERS=$(cat /tmp/players.list | sed '/Players connected/q' | egrep -v '^$' | egrep -v "^LOG" | sed -e 's/^-/\\\\\n/')`

I get a JSON error:

[image]

OK, removing **TWO** "/"s and the new-lines just don't work:

[image]

Comment: I'd recommend using `jq` to generate the JSON, rather than trying to format it with bash, sed, etc (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468117/generate-json-out-of-command-line-arguments)). Note that when you use `jq --arg`, you should pass the raw data you want encoded in the JSON, so use an actual newline character instead of `\n` (i.e. a backslash followed by the letter "n").

Answer (score 1):

I understand the problem with `PLAYERS` variable generation.

Suggesting to debug with `set -x` and and `set +x` to inspect the variable:

```
set -x # enable debug trace
PLAYERS=$(cat /tmp/players.list | sed '/Players connected/q' | egrep -v '^$' | egrep -v "^LOG" | sed -e 's/^-/\\\\\n/')
echo "PLAYERS=$PLAYERS" # debug trace
set +x # disable debug trace
```

Suggesting to try test the `PLAYERS` command step by step:

```
PLAYERS1=$(sed '/Players connected/q' /tmp/players.list)
echo "PLAYERS1=$PLAYERS1" # debug trace
```

This should print /tmp/players.list all lines until found RegExp pattern `/Players connected/`

```
PLAYERS2=$(sed '/Players connected/q' /tmp/players.list| egrep -v '^([[:space:]]*$|LOG)')
echo "PLAYERS2=$PLAYERS2" # debug trace
```

This should print /tmp/players.list all lines until found RegExp pattern `/Players connected/`.

Filtering out empty lines, and Lines starting with `LOG`

```
PLAYERS3=$(sed '/Players connected/q' /tmp/players.list| egrep -v '^([[:space:]]*$|LOG)'| sed -e 's|^-|\\\\\n|')
echo "PLAYERS3=$PLAYERS3" # debug trace
```

This should print /tmp/players.list all lines until found RegExp pattern `/Players connected/`.

Filtering out empty lines, and Lines starting with `LOG`

And replacing lines starting with `-` to `\\` followed by new line.

For example:

```
  line 1
  -line 2
```

Will transform:

```
  line 1
  \\
  line 2
```

If you want to concat the lines with `\\n` the command is:

```
PLAYERS4=$(sed '/Players connected/q' /tmp/players.list|egrep -v '^([[:space:]]*$|LOG)'| sed -z 's|\n-|\\\\n|')
echo "PLAYERS4=$PLAYERS4" # debug trace
```

For example:

```
  line 1
  -line 2
```

Will transform:

```
  line 1\\nline 2
```

It is possible to simplify/fold the `sed` commands and `egrep` command into single `awk` command.

```
PLAYERS5=$(awk '!/^([[:space:]]*$|LOG)/{sub("-","\\\\n");print $0}' ORS="" /tmp/players.list)
echo "PLAYERS5=$PLAYERS5" # debug trace
```

Once you have the desired `PLAYERS` list.
Make sure you feed them correctly in `JSON` format.

#### Finally.

Suggesting to use `jq` command to prepare a valid `JSON` single-line string or an object from `$PLAYERS`.

Comment: Wow, nice and thorough answer, thanks for that; I really appreciate it. I'm going to try and work through this now, but suspect that I'm going to run out of time and will only really be able to dive into this on Friday.

Comment: Ok, so 1: i'm unfamiliar with `jq` , keen to learn more, so I will be digging deaper into that. As for the `/tmp/players.list` file, I've manually gone and edited a generated file to include more members in it for testing. The file (as oppoesed to generating it each time) End result would be the same though. The output for adding the above (and a seperator to make easy reading is here: https://pastebin.com/GueziTah (excluding the obligatory JSON failure :-)