# ANSI color codes with jq

Tags: json, bash, colors, jq, ansi-escape

Trying to make `jq` work with ANSI color codes.

Test cases:

```
$ echo '{"a":"b","c":"d"}' | jq -r .c
d # Matches my expected output

$ echo '{"a":"b","c":"\033[31md\033[0m"}' | jq -r .c
parse error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 31 # returns err code 4

$ echo '{"a":"b","c":"d"}' | jq -r '"foo"+.c+"bar"'
foodbar # Correct

$ echo '{"a":"b","c":"d"}' | jq -r '"\033[31m"+.c+"\033[0m"'
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\0"') at <top-level>, line 1:
"\033[31m"+.c+"\033[0m"
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\0"') at <top-level>, line 1:
"\033[31m"+.c+"\033[0m"
jq: 2 compile errors # returns err code 3

$ jq -rn '"\033[31mbar\033[0m"'
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\0"') at <top-level>, line 1:
"\033[31mbar\033[0m"
jq: error: Invalid escape at line 1, column 4 (while parsing '"\0"') at <top-level>, line 1:
"\033[31mbar\033[0m"
jq: 2 compile errors # returns err code 4
```

P.S. in case it matters, I am using the `bash` shell with version `5.1.16(1)-release` on Linux.

Conslusion: ANSI colors do not work with `jq`, whether in the JSON string or directly concatenating it through the `+` operator.

Question: how to make ANSI colors work in `jq`? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Octal escape sequences are not valid JSON syntax, so you need to encode the ASCII escape character as `\u001b` rather than `\033`. Also, to add to the confusion, some versions of `echo` will attempt to interpret backslash (escape) sequences itself before passing them to `jq`, so in cases like this it's [much safer to use `printf '%s\n'`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo):

```
$ printf '%s\n' '{"a":"b","c":"\u001b[31md\u001b[0m"}' | jq -r .c
d
```

(You can't see it, but that "d" is red in my terminal.)

BTW, an easy way to find things like this out is to get `jq` to encode them in JSON for you. Here, I'll set the shell variable to the actual string (using bash's `$'...'` string format, which interprets ANSI-C escape sequences like `\033`), then [use `--arg` to pass that to `jq`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468117/generate-json-out-of-command-line-arguments):

```
$ seq=$'\033[31md\033[0m'
$ jq -nc --arg seq "$seq" '{"a":"b","c":$seq}'
{"a":"b","c":"\u001b[31md\u001b[0m"}
```